# redis connect timeout to remote server in a docker

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I start a redis container with docker-compose in machine A.

docker-compose.yml.

```
redis:
    ports:
    - "6379:6379"
    image: redis
```

on machine A, I can connect to it with redis-cli in terminal.

```
redis-cli 
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

But I can't connect to it use A's IP on machine B even on machine A itself.

on machine B or A.

```
redis-cli -h 10.10.10.25
Could not connect to Redis at 10.10.10.25:6379: Connection timed out
not connected>
```

Comment: Redis is listening on the localhost only, probably. See `127.0.0.1`

Comment: in `redis.conf` there is the `bind` configuration. set it to `bind 10.10.10.25` and restart redis.

Comment: No need to change redis.conf. There should be other problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange. I can run redis-cli on both host A and host B with A's IP. 
Following is the output of "docker ps"

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
a59c39bf448e        redis               "/entrypoint.sh redis"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp   test_redis_1
```

After mapping port 6379 of redis container to the host port 6379. The redis service should be available for all network interfaces(0.0.0.0) of host A. So you don't have to change the redis configuration.

Can you show the output of "docker ps"?

Comment: Could you please guide here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583036/unable-to-connect-to-redis-from-docker ?